Ensure sshd is running after update/restart
Sometimes when I update and restart a beaglebone with Debian, it's not reachable with ssh anymore, and somehow stuck, e.g.:

I can ping the machine
nmap shows port 22 as filtered
netcat shows nothing connecting to port 22
python sockets can still recv the "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH..." message when connecting

Is there a possiblity to verify sshd from within the beaglebone, so that it can restart itself?

What is the SSHD configuration? Is it set to auto-start? https://askubuntu.com/questions/3913/start-ssh-server-on-boot

On another beaglebone sudo systemctl status ssh.socket was disabled, I could still login with ssh. What is ssh.socket doing?
And usually the beaglebones come back after a restart.

what is the output of netstat -ntlup | grep 22 ? does it show the local address as 0.0.0.0:22? How long is it stuck? usually it takes a minute or two after OS boot to bring SSHD up.

The issue could also be on network/routing or firewall (because if it was only ssh, nmap should show the port as closed, not filtered).
